# Login Loop in 13.10 After Installing AMD Propietary Driver

Tags: drivers, ati, login, 13.10

Just installed AMD Propietary drivers using [this method](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Saucy_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29).

When I rebooted after install I was not able to login to the desktop. Once the password is entered, it displays a black screen and loops back to the login screen. I also used the multi monitor config for xorg.

Comment: have you done the "in case of failure" part in the wiki?

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps but I had huge issues after trying out the AMD drivers yesterday. I had to revert back to default drivers via the recovery menu root shell..